# Save extension's state (on or off)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to save state of the extension. If it's on, the code will run on a specific website and if it's not, then it won't.

I have yet to understand how to do it, since i don't understand it fully.

This is the html of the checkbox:

```
<div class="onOff">
      <label class="switch">
        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="saveValue" />
        <span class="slider round" id="theSwitch"></span>
      </label>

      <span id="onOroff">OFF</span>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery code which just changes the color and text when you click on the button (bg color, on/off text).

```
    if ($("#checkbox").is(":checked")) {
      $("#onOroff").text("OFF");
      $(".slider").css({ "background-color": "#C75052" });
    } else {
      $("#onOroff").text("ON");
      $(".slider").css({ "background-color": "#50c878" });
    }
  });
```

Here you can see the extension: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FBsV.jpg

When you click on the extension and open it, Chrome sees it as just another page being opened, so when I turn the extension on (click on Off) and close the extension window, re-open it, it doesn't save that state.

I figure I need to save check/unchecked in a variable, pass that onto chrome.Storage and have chrome.storage save last version of the button (green or red, green means it' checked).